# Pull OVRCameraRig over RTS map via touch controller grabbing gesture

Tags: unity, c#, camera, virtual-reality, oculus

Currently developing a little prototype RTS with the Oculus VR devkit.
I want to implement camera movement via "grabbing" onto the world space with a touch controller and move the OVRCameraRig object on the X- and Z-axes. For the prototype purpose, I rather decided to go with a simpler approach, namely just pull the map around, since it's not that big, and not much is happening on it.

So far I got this script:

```
public class MapMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool movementEnabled;

    Transform map;
    Transform leftController;
    Vector3 offset;

    public bool IsMovementEnabled { get { return movementEnabled; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        leftController = GameObject.Find("LeftHandAnchor").transform;
    }

    public void BeginMovement()
    {
        offset = transform.position - leftController.position;
        movementEnabled = true;
    }

    public void EndMovement()
    {
        movementEnabled = false;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (movementEnabled)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(
                (leftController.position.x * 1.1f + offset.x),
                transform.position.y,
                (leftController.position.z * 1.1f + offset.z)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

`BeginMovement()` is called when I press the Hand Trigger on the left Touch controller. My current results are unproductive: The first `BeginMovement()` call is sufficient, but the movement of the map is very minimal, since the controller models are tiny and their position clamps around `-1.0f` and `1.0f`. The second call of `BeginMovement()` makes the map do a jump to either side before going back to the minimal movement.

My question is, what exactly am I missing? Is there a simpler approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my approach to the problem and came up with a basic solution that supports my needs:

```
public class MapMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool movementEnabled;
    private float factor = 45.0f;

    Transform leftController;

    Vector3 lastControllerPosition;
    Vector3 currentControllerPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        leftController = GameObject.Find("LeftHandAnchor").transform;
        currentControllerPosition = leftController.transform.position;
    }

    public void BeginMovement() { movementEnabled = true; }

    public void EndMovement() { movementEnabled = false; }

    private void Update()
    {
        lastControllerPosition = currentControllerPosition;
        currentControllerPosition = leftController.transform.position;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (movementEnabled) {
            Vector3 distance = currentControllerPosition - lastControllerPosition;
            transform.Translate(distance.x * factor, 0, distance.z * factor);
        }
    }
}
```

Basic function explained:

The script is a component of the map object and is initialized with the current position of the left controller's `transform.position`. Each frame, this value is moved to the last position, while the current position is retrieved anew. During the `LateUpdate()`, upon meeting the condition of being moved, the difference between current and last position is calculated, and the map object is translated by the result's X- and Z-values multiplied by a factor (after extensive testing, a factor of `45.0f` seems comfortable for moving around, but you should definitely test it out to meet your needs).

I hope this will help someone.